# Trouble proving an inequality in a triangle related to incircles of the two triangles obtained upon drawing the median

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have a triangle ABC and let M be the midpoint of side BC of triangle ABC and let $r_1$ and $r_2$ be the radii of the two incircles of triangles ABM and ACM. I need to prove that $r_1 < 2r_2$.

First of all I feel that the question is quite incomplete since if I interchange $r_1$ and $r_2$ then does it still make complete sense since nothing is mentioned about the lengths of the sides or is it true no matter what I take to be $r_1$ and $r_2$.

However, upon directly using the formula for inradius, and after some gruelling work, if my calculation is correct then I need to prove the following inequality

$$ a^2 + b^2 + 7c^2 - 2ab + 4ac - 8bc < 0$$

How do I prove this?

Comment: The interchangeability of $r_1$ and $r_2$ isn't problematic. You can have $r_1<2r_2$ and $r_2<2r_1$ simultaneously; combining the relations says $\frac12 r_2 < r_1 < 2r_2$ (or vice-versa). The idea here is simply that neither inradius can get super-large compared to the other.

Comment: The inequality you've obtained does not hold when $a=b=c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $AM=m.$

Now, $\frac{r_1}{r_2}=\frac{s_1}{s_2}, as \space \Delta_1=\Delta_2.$ (How?)

$$\therefore \frac{r_1}{r_2}=\frac{\frac{a}{2}+m+c}{\frac{a}{2}+m+b}=1+\frac{c-b}{\frac{a}{2}+m+b}$$

Now, try to prove that $$-\frac{1}{2}<\frac{c-b}{\frac{a}{2}+m+b}<1$$

Or you may assume without loss of genarality that $c>b$ and prove just the right hand inequality as both are equivalent(Why?).

Hint: Use triangle inequality.

Comment: I just want to confirm that the answer to your second Why is that in case b > c, I interchange $r_1$ and $r_2$ and then prove the same inequality with $b-c$ in place of $c-b$? Thanks for the help, simple triangle inequality proved the right hand inequality